# Bash: List files with absolute paths, one per line, no other information

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

I am looking for a command that lists all files in the current directory.

Requirements:

1. Absolute paths
2. One file per line
3. No other information (like size, permissions...)
4. Don't show folders

What I got so far is this:

```
ls -d1 $PWD/*
```

Which gives:

```
[User@User-arch Pictures]$ ls -d1 $PWD/*
/home/User/Pictures/folder1
/home/User/Pictures/folder2
/home/User/Pictures/file1.png
/home/User/Pictures/file2.png
/home/User/Pictures/file3.png
/home/User/Pictures/file4.png
```

or `readlink -f $PWD/*`, which gives the same output.

They satisfie all but the 4. requirements. How can I tweak it so it does not show folders? Or is there a simpler command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find $PWD -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Lists files in current working directory. `-type f` tells `find` list only regular files (no folders), `-maxdepth 1` prevents content in subfolders showing up in output.

Answer (score 1):

You could tell `ls` to include the trailing forward slash after directory names then pipe it to `grep`.

```
ls -pd1 $PWD/* | grep -v /$
```

Edit: Saw my flaw in original answer.

Comment: That doesnt show anything for me